# How can I learn to convert recursive solution to iterative solution while preserving the space complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration, binary-tree

I am trying to solve a easy binary tree question to convert the existing binary tree to a sum tree.
The recursive solution for this is :

```
class Solution{
    public void toSumTree(Node root){
         solve(root);
    }
    private int solve(Node node){
        if(node == null){
            return 0;
        }
        
        int leftSubtreeValue = solve(node.left);
        int rightSubtreeValue = solve(node.right);
        int currentNodeValue = node.data;
        
        node.data = leftSubtreeValue + rightSubtreeValue;
        
        return currentNodeValue + leftSubtreeValue + rightSubtreeValue;
    }
}
```

This give us the time and space complexity as O(N) and O(H) respectively.

Now since the above recursive approach is similar to post-order traversal, I think we can use some version of iterative post-order travesal like below :

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> postorderTraversal(TreeNode root) { 
        List<Integer> postOrderTrvNodes = new LinkedList<>();
        if(root == null){
             return postOrderTrvNodes;
         }
        Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
        TreeNode current = root;
        TreeNode lastVisited = null;
        while (!stack.isEmpty() || current != null) {
            if (current != null) {
                stack.push(current);
                current = current.left;
            } else {
                TreeNode peekNode = stack.peek();
                if (peekNode.right != null && peekNode.right != lastVisited) {
                    current = peekNode.right;
                } else {
                    TreeNode poppedNode = stack.pop();
                    postOrderTrvNodes.add(poppedNode.val);
                    lastVisited = poppedNode;
                }
            }
        }
        return postOrderTrvNodes;
    }
}
```

What I am not able to come up with is how to store the required sum of subtree at each node so that space complexity remains O(H). If we use a HashMap that stores sum of subtree at current node in a HashMap<Node, Integer> then the space complexity will become O(N).

What I want is some protocol that can be followed in general to mimic what Java is doing with internal stack.

Comment: Why not use a `Stack<Pair<TreeNode,Integer>>` to store the value?

Comment: Preserving space complexity == the same overhead as recursive solution. Then you're right since the stack pushes will basically be similar to the call stack in a recursive solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but the following iterative function will return a post-order traversal of the given tree, in O(N) steps and with O(H) space.

```
public static List<Integer> postorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
    final List<Integer> results = new LinkedList<>();

    final Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
    final Stack<Boolean> dirStack = new Stack<>();

    TreeNode curr = root;

    while (!stack.isEmpty() || curr != null) {
        if (curr == null) {
            curr = stack.pop();
            final boolean up = dirStack.pop();
            if (up) {
                results.add(curr.value);
                curr = null;
            }
        } else {
            stack.push(curr);
            dirStack.push(true);
            stack.push(curr.right);
            dirStack.push(false);
            curr = curr.left;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

A simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final TreeNode root =
            new TreeNode(
                    new TreeNode(
                            new TreeNode(1),
                            5,
                            new TreeNode(
                                    new TreeNode(2),
                                    4,
                                    new TreeNode(3))
                    ),
                    9,
                    new TreeNode(
                            new TreeNode(6),
                            8,
                            new TreeNode(7)
                    )
            );

    final List<Integer> l = postorderTraversal(root);

    System.out.println("PostorderTraversal = " + l);
}
```

outputs the following:

```
PostorderTraversal = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The algorithm is derived by considering the recursive solution for a post-order tree traversal. For each node it has three steps:

1. Process left node.
2. Process right node.
3. Add node value to list.

When we convert this to an iterative solution, we need to effectively defer steps 2 & 3 by pushing them onto a stack, and then proceeed with step 1. Step 2 & 3 both require a node from the stack, but we also require a boolean flag to distinguish the two steps. I.e. we need a stack of nodes *and a stack of boolean values*.

Comment: Good, but having done similar things, I would recommend two changes: Use one stack with a pair/tuple of nodes and boolean values etc, instead of two different stacks. And consider using an integer to indicate the state, since that generalizes if you have more than two recursive calls.

Comment: @HansOlsson Yep, my first version did exactly that, however I changed it to two stacks as it was less code overall.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have space complexity of O(H), that is, space required is directly proportional to the height of the tree,

you can use two `Stack`s one for right subtree and other for left subtree to maintain the sum of left and right subtree respectively,

The stacks will have `List<Integer>`s in which the first element of the list will denote the level or height the `TreeNode` and the second element will denote the sum of the subtree in which the `TreeNode` is root node. Then by determining whether the current `TreeNode` is left child or right child of it's parent we can save the sum in relevant stack.

```java
public static List<Integer> postorderTraversal(TreeNode root) { 
    List<Integer> postOrderTrvNodes = new LinkedList<>();
    if(root == null){
         return postOrderTrvNodes;
     }
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();

    //

    Stack<List<Integer>> leftStack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<List<Integer>> rightStack = new Stack<>();

    leftStack.push(Arrays.asList(0, 0));

    //

    TreeNode current = root;
    TreeNode lastVisited = null;

    while (!stack.isEmpty() || current != null) {
        if (current != null) {
            stack.push(current);
            current = current.left;
            //
            if (current != null) {
                List<Integer> lpk = leftStack.peek();
                if(!rightStack.isEmpty()) {
                    List<Integer> rpk = rightStack.peek();
                    if(rpk.get(0) > lpk.get(0)) {
                        leftStack.push(Arrays.asList(rpk.get(0) + 1, 0));
                    } else {
                        leftStack.push(Arrays.asList(lpk.get(0) + 1, 0));
                    }
                } else {
                    leftStack.push(Arrays.asList(lpk.get(0) + 1, 0));
                }
            }
            //
        } else {
            TreeNode peekNode = stack.peek();
            if (peekNode.right != null && peekNode.right != lastVisited) {
                current = peekNode.right;
                //
                if(!rightStack.isEmpty()) {
                    List<Integer> rpk = rightStack.peek();
                    List<Integer> lpk = leftStack.peek();
                    if(rpk.get(0) > lpk.get(0)) {
                        rightStack.push(Arrays.asList(rpk.get(0) + 1, 0));
                    } else {
                        rightStack.push(Arrays.asList(lpk.get(0) + 1, 0));
                    }
                } else if(rightStack.isEmpty() && !leftStack.isEmpty()) {
                    List<Integer> lpk = leftStack.peek();
                    rightStack.push(Arrays.asList(lpk.get(0) + 1, 0));
                } else {
                    List<Integer> rpk = rightStack.peek();
                    rightStack.push(Arrays.asList(rpk.get(0) + 1, 0));
                }
                //
            } else {
                TreeNode poppedNode = stack.pop();
                
                // right subtree fully explored and parent is a left child
                
                if(rightStack.isEmpty() && !leftStack.isEmpty()) {
                    List<Integer> nd = leftStack.pop();
                    int nv = nd.get(1) + poppedNode.val;
                    postOrderTrvNodes.add(nv);

                    if (!leftStack.isEmpty()) {
                        List<Integer> lpk = leftStack.peek();
                        lpk.set(1, lpk.get(1) + nv);
                    }
                }
                // left subtree fully explored and parent is a right child
                else if(leftStack.isEmpty() && !rightStack.isEmpty()) {
                    List<Integer> nd = rightStack.pop();
                    int nv = nd.get(1) + poppedNode.val;
                    postOrderTrvNodes.add(nv);
                    
                    if (!rightStack.isEmpty()) {
                        List<Integer> rpk = rightStack.peek();
                        rpk.set(1, rpk.get(1) + nv);
                    }
                } else {
                    List<Integer> rpk = rightStack.peek();
                    List<Integer> lpk = leftStack.peek();
                    
                    int lh = lpk.get(0);
                    int rh = rpk.get(0);
                    
                    // node is right child of parent
                    if(lh < rh) {
                        int nv = rpk.get(1) + poppedNode.val;
                        postOrderTrvNodes.add(nv);
                        rightStack.pop();

                        List<Integer> nlpk = leftStack.peek();

                        if(!rightStack.isEmpty()) {
                            List<Integer> nrpk = rightStack.peek();
                            // parent is right child of grandparent
                            if(nlpk.get(0) < nrpk.get(0)) {
                                nrpk.set(1, nrpk.get(1) + nv);
                            } else {
                                // parent is left child of grandparent
                                nlpk.set(1, nlpk.get(1) + nv);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // parent is left child of grandparent
                            nlpk.set(1, nlpk.get(1) + nv);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // node is left child of parent
                    if(lh > rh) {
                        int nv = lpk.get(1) + poppedNode.val;
                        postOrderTrvNodes.add(nv);
                        leftStack.pop();
                        
                        List<Integer> nrpk = rightStack.peek();

                        if(!leftStack.isEmpty()) {
                            
                            List<Integer> nlpk = leftStack.peek();
                            //
                            if(nlpk.get(0) > nrpk.get(0)) {
                                nlpk.set(1, nlpk.get(1) + nv);
                            } else {
                                nrpk.set(1, nrpk.get(1) + nv);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //
                            nrpk.set(1, nrpk.get(1) + nv);
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                //

                // postOrderTrvNodes.add(poppedNode.val);

                lastVisited = poppedNode;
            }
        }
    }
    return postOrderTrvNodes;
}
```

You can optimize the code further by maybe using a different data structure like `Pair<Integer>` instead of `List<Integer>`.

I programmed the code in `python` and then converted it to the java code above the original python code is added below

```py
def poTravel(tn: TreeNode):
    st, po = [], []

    current = tn

    lv = None

    ls, rs = [[0, 0]], []

    while st or current:
        if current:
            st.append(current)
            current = current.left
            if current:
                if rs and rs[-1][0] > ls[-1][0]:
                    ls.append([rs[-1][0] + 1 if rs else 1, 0])
                else:
                    ls.append([ls[-1][0] + 1 if ls else 1, 0])

        else:
            if st[-1].right and lv != st[-1].right:
                current = st[-1].right
                if rs and ls[-1][0] > rs[-1][0]:
                    rs.append([ls[-1][0] + 1 if ls else 1, 0])
                elif not rs and ls:
                    rs.append([ls[-1][0] + 1 if ls else 1, 0])
                else:
                    rs.append([rs[-1][0] + 1 if rs else 1, 0])

            else:
                nd = st.pop()

                if not rs and ls:
                    nv = ls[-1][1] + nd.val
                    po.append(nv)
                    ls.pop()
                    if ls:
                        ls[-1][1] += nv

                elif not ls and rs:
                    nv = rs[-1][1] + nd.val
                    po.append(nv)
                    rs.pop()
                    if rs:
                        rs[-1][1] += nv

                elif ls[-1][0] < rs[-1][0]:
                    nv = rs[-1][1] + nd.val
                    po.append(nv)
                    rs.pop()
                    if rs and ls[-1][0] < rs[-1][0]:
                        rs[-1][1] += nv
                    else:
                        ls[-1][1] += nv

                elif rs[-1][0] < ls[-1][0]:
                    nv = ls[-1][1] + nd.val
                    po.append(nv)
                    ls.pop()
                    if ls and rs[-1][0] < ls[-1][0]:
                        ls[-1][1] += nv
                    else:
                        rs[-1][1] += nv

                lv = nd

    return po
```